# Response.Redirect in Page_Load

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect

I have a `Response.Redirect` in my `Page_Load`:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ...Code
    Response.Redirect("http://www.mysite.com")
End Sub
```

I have other Subroutines with working code before adding the Response.Redirect

When the `Response.Redirect` is added they all do not process their code and automatically execute the `Response.Redirect` website.

My code works when there is no `Response.Redirect`.

Comment: What code are you trying to execute? a `Response.Redirect` will tell the browser to request the given page/site. If you're not storing it somewhere, then the next page won't know what you did _in memory_.

Comment: one method compiled in server then response to client. then code in page load compiled complete then redirect to other page.

Comment: What makes you think that "When the Response.Redirect is added they all do not process their code "?

Answer (score 12):

Use

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.mysite.com",  false)
```

second parameter Indicates whether execution of the current page should terminate or not.

if you use `Response.Redirect("http://www.mysite.com")`, current page execution will terminate

Answer (score 6):

Please Use

```
Response.Redirect("http://example.com",  false)
```

According to [PRB: ThreadAbortException Occurs If You Use Response.End, Response.Redirect, or Server.Transfer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/en-us):

> If you use the Response.End, Response.Redirect, or Server.Transfer
>   method, a ThreadAbortException exception occurs. You can use a
>   try-catch statement to catch this exception.
>
> The **Response.End** method ends the page execution and shifts the
>   execution to the Application_EndRequest event in the application's
>   event pipeline. The line of code that follows Response.End is not
>   executed.
>
> This problem occurs in the **Response.Redirect** and
>   **Server.Transfer** methods because both methods call Response.End internally.
>
> **To work around this problem, use one of the following methods:**
>
> For **Response.End**, call the
>   **HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest** method instead of **Response.End** to bypass the code execution to the
>   Application_EndRequest event.
>
> For **Response.Redirect**, use an overload, **Response.Redirect(String
>   url, bool endResponse)** that passes false for the endResponse
>   parameter to suppress the internal call to Response.End. For example: 
>   Response.Redirect ("nextpage.aspx", false);
>                          If you use this workaround, the code that follows Response.Redirect is executed. For Server.Transfer, use the
>   Server.Execute method instead.

Comment: How your answer is different from Damith's answer?

Comment: Yes, just don't repeat same thing. Before answering check if anyone already posted that. If I were you, I would remove my answer and upvote the other answer.