# Check if user session is active

Tags: asp.net

I'm using ASP.NET to build a web app, and use the following code to validate if the user session still active:

```
    If Session("CurrentUser") Is Nothing Then
       Response.Redirect("LoginPage.aspx")
    End If
```

in the Page_Load.

Am I have to check the same in each method in this page? or it is engugh to do it in the Page_Load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be enough to do this in `Page_Load`, since that's invoked on every request to the page.  (Initial load as well as post-backs)

According to the [ASP.NET Page Lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178472(v=vs.140)), the Load event occurs before any of the control-specific events (such as a button click), so you can redirect or otherwise cancel the rest of the event logic from within `Page_Load`.

There's also some information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20579883/328193) about what a redirect means to thread execution and how you can control whether the rest of the page logic should be invoked or not.